# Проблемы с триггерами и с тегами

Tags: unity3d

я устал с этим бороться, суть проблемы:

1. Есть один триггер и есть два объекта с двумя разными тегами.
2. Нужно чтобы триггер ловил двух объектов и сравнивал их по тегу и тогда выводил бы принт, я сделал так:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
 { 
 if(other.transform.tag == "circle" && other.transform.tag == "cross") 
 { 
 print("Test"); 
 } 
}
```

но в теории я прекрасно понимаю что два объекта со своим тегами оказываются в одном триггере то должно сработать условие и вывести принт но на практике этого не работает, может я что то упустил?

Comment: у одного объекта может быть два тега?

Comment: Вы понимаете значение кода, который написан? Вы ожидаете, что ОДИН и ТОТ ЖЕ объект будет с тегами "circle" и "cross"?

Answer (score -1):

В этой строке ошибка:

```
if(other.transform.tag == "circle" && other.transform.tag == "cross")
```

У одного объекта не может быть два тега.
Нужно делать как-то по другому, например так:

```
if(other.transform.tag == "circle")
print("circle");
if(other.transform.tag == "cross")
print("cross");
```